# Uri activation to "ms-appdata:///local/"

Tags: c#, uwp

Running this code below gives me this unexpected result:

[image]

```
    private async void OpenItemAppBarBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaViewModel media = MyListView.SelectedItem as MediaViewModel;

        if (media.VidOrPic)
        {
            var uriString = "ms-appdata:///local/" + media.Name + ".mp4";
            Uri muUri = new Uri(uriString);
            Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else
        {
            var uriString = "ms-appdata:///local/" + media.Name + ".jpeg";
            Uri muUri = new Uri(uriString);
            Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }   
    }
```

UriString Content:

[image]

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: The default App. launching my Pic/Vid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to run the file use Launcher.LaunchFileAsync, not Launcher.LaunchUriAsync

```
var uriString = "ms-appdata:///local/" + media.Name + ".mp4";
Uri muUri = new Uri(uriString);
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(muUri);
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` method always shows the application picker, if no default application is associated with the `Uri` you provide.

However, there's an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx):

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(Uri, LauncherOptions)
```

The launcher options allow you to set a property called `DisplayApplicationPicker`. If the default app is defined **and** you set this value to true, using the overload, the application will start directly, without displaying the application picker.